# Can my app have login authentication and be open source?

Tags: open-source-definition

This might be a bit of a stupid question. But can I have login features (so send data to my server) and have my app be open-source? Or might this be a security risk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is very much possible to perform a login action with an open-source app without incurring a security risk.

For a secure system, the only thing that can not be made public are the credentials that are used to perform the login. Then you should think of usernames and passwords.

Comment: Alright! Thank you for the response!